# Why can't you access parts of a class in C# like you could a struct in C++?

Tags: c#

```
namespace SnakesAndLadders
{

    class Node
    {
        int snakeHead ;   // points to another node where the player goes down to 
        int ladderFoot;  // points to another node where to player goes up to
    }

    class Program
    {
        Node[] gameBoard = new Node[100];

        void loadStructure()
        {
            // first, set all the snakeheads and ladderFoots to zero
            for (int i =0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                gameBoard[i].snakeHead = 0;
                gameBoard[i].ladderFoot = 0;
            }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
    }
```

In C#, this won't work.  For gameBoard[i], intellisense does not show it has a component  of snakehead.

Comment: `snakeHead` is a private field..

Comment: by default all classes unless literally declared as `public` are `private` the same goes for its `member variables`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C# fields of a class are private by default

```
class Node
{
    public int snakeHead ;   // points to another node where the player goes down to 
    public int ladderFoot;  // points to another node where to player goes up to
}
```

Just making your fields public should fix your issue. 
EDIT: using best practices you would keep fields private, but create properties and use them to deal with your data.  Also naming private with an underscore is a common practice:

```
class Node
{
    private int _snakeHead ;   // points to another node where the player goes down to 
    public int SnakeHead
    {
        get {return _snakeHead;}
        set {_snakeHead = value;}
    }

    private int _ladderFoot;  // points to another node where to player goes up to
    public int LadderFoot
    {
        get {return _ladderFoot;}
        set {_ladderFoot = value;}
    }
}
```

Comment: Just for clarity. The statement for classes is incorrect. By default top classes are not `private`, but `internal`. What you wrote applies to nested classes.

Comment: You are right that in c# class members default access modifier is private but classes default access modifier is internal not private. BTW using public fields is a big bad practice that breaks encapsulation, properties should be prefered in these situations.

Comment: thank you @SomeUser

Answer (score 2):

Answer to your question:
In C++ fields of struct are `public` by default

In C# fields of struct are `private` by default

You have declared fields without access modifier keyword (`private.`public`) so they have default accessibility mentioned above.

To get same behavior in C# you need declare access modifier explicitly

```
struct Node
{
    public int snakeHead ;to 
    public int ladderFoot;
}
```

Notice that in C++ fields of classes are `private` by default.

Answer (score 0):

The default access modifier is `private`. Create properties to access your private fields.

```
class Node
{
    int snakeHead ;   // points to another node where the player goes down to 
    int ladderFoot;  // points to another node where to player goes up to

    public int SnakeHead
    {
        get { return snakeHead;}
        set { snakeHead = value;}
    }

    public int LadderFoot
    {
        get { return ladderFoot; }
        set { ladderFoot = value;}
    }
}
```

After that you can `gameBoard[i].SnakeHead = 0;`

You can even define the properties like this:

```
public int SnakeHead{get; set;}
```

In this case you will not even need the private fields.